# Net tcp Binding Service:The request was aborted: The request was canceled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am uploading files to Amazon S3.

1.While uploading large files(upto 50 MB) I am getting this error:

The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

2.The problem is when I dont use the net tcp binding service and directly upload from UI to business layer without a service layer in between,I am able to upload without any exceptions.

3.Here is the exception details:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.     at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)     at System.IO.Stream.Close()     at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getRequestStreamCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)

4.In the service's web. config I have increased the timeout of both idle and receive to more than half an hour. But still getting the exception.

5.Is this related to any configuration settings for the net tcp binding service?

Any solution?

Comment: Load it up in the WCF test client and see what timeout values it defaults to in the config.